# Why are Vestaldt's, Nashandra's and Throne Watcher/Defender Souls similar?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Ok so it's pretty self explanatory why Nashandra's soul has a "dark" appearance, (she is Manus, and Manus' soul was almost identical) but why do the Throne Watcher, the Throne Defender, and Vestaldt's have a similar appearance? Weren't they working against the queen?

The only time she shows herself to you is after you have reclaimed the King's Ring, (killed Vestaldt) and cleared the Throne of Want, (defeated the Throne duo). So if they were corrupted by the dark, would they not be working to help Nashandra?

Artorias (in DkS1) was corrupted by the dark, and his soul has a similar appearance, but even he had the sense to attempt to ward you off, in hopes that you would not fall to the Dark, before he was completely overtaken. Source: [Cut Artorias Dialogue](http://youtu.be/upzLAJhtnvk)

Comment: You'll be wanting to add spoiler tags on your question before someone downvotes it.

Comment: The spoiler tag no longer exists. Good riddance. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/spoiler-alert-spoiler-dies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the lore of the Souls series is intentionally left open to interpretation, this is mostly speculation.

**Nashandra** was born from fragments of Manus, she is pure dark.

**The Throne Watcher** and **The Throne Defender** did just that, they watched and defended the throne, *they serve Nashandra*.

As for **Velstadt**, opinions vary, but a theory I like is that he isn't actually protecting Vendrick, but making sure he can't get out.

As you can see in the game, Vendrick has completely hollowed, which implies that he couldn't have gotten to any souls.

Which in turn means Velstadt didn't let him out to get souls.

So the way I see it is that just like Artorias, they've all been corrupted.

Comment: Interesting point... It completely goes against my theory of the overall story, (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169501/what-does-the-ending-to-dark-souls-2-mean/169539#169539) but I'm not saying it's wrong...

Answer (score -1):

Veldstadt was once one with miracles but prolonged exposure to the undead crypt have blackened his appearance and darkened himself. He protects Vendrick as he waits in a circle of light, keeping a barrier between himself and the crypt to prevent total corruption. 
Simple theory based of the games lore.